# How to use the static image Path passed as props in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My Parent component

```
import React from "react";
import TopModal from "./components/topModal";

// passing productImage to the Child Component
import productImage from "../../../../../../assets/images/juices.jpg"; 

import { makeStyles, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
// md 6

const styles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "black",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: "2em 0",
  },
}));

const ModifierModal: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = styles();

  const modalInput = (
    productName: string,
    productWeight: Number,
    price: Number,
    image: any,
    condiments: Array<any>
  ) => {
    return {
      productName,
      productWeight,
      price,
      image,
      condiments,
    };
  };

  const productModalModifier = modalInput("Big John", 650, 7.25, productImage, [
    "Shredded Lettuce",
    "Cheese",
    "Beef",
    "BBQ Sauce",
  ]);

  return (
    <Grid container md={6} className={classes.root}>
      <TopModal data={productModalModifier} />
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default ModifierModal;
```

My Child Component

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import BottomModal from "../bottomModal";


interface ModalProps {
  data: any;
}

const TopModal: React.FC<ModalProps> = (props: ModalProps) => {
  const classes = styles();

  const { data } = props;
  console.log("data props is ", data);
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.flex}>
        <CardActionArea>
          <div className={classes.mediaDiv}>
            <CardMedia
              className={classes.media}
              component="img"
              alt="ProductCard"
              image={data.productImage} // Does not work
              title={data.productName}
            />
          </div>
  </CardActionArea>
```

On Consoling out  the `data.productImage`, I get `image: "/static/media/juices.761005d6.jpg"`. Now, how can I use this image static path to actually display the image ? I am not getting any errors just the image does not show up. How can I display the image using the image that I have passed as props from the Parent component to the Child Component

Comment: May I know if there's a specific reason you need to group the props together as an object before you pass them into your child component?

Answer (score 0):

You need put your `static` folder in the `public` folder, same level as the `index.html` file

[image]